# Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [custom_score]

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a custom score on a multi match query with the following query:

```
GET /product/_search
{
  "custom_score": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "multi_match" : {
            "query":    "casual shirt", 
            "type": "best_fields",
            "fields": [ "brandTitle^15", "title^10", "details^5" ],
            "tie_breaker": 1,
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "term": {
            "inStock": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "params": {
        "scoreWeighting": 2,
        "popularityWeighting": 5
    },
    "script": "scoreWeighting * _score + popularityWeighting * doc['popularity'].value"
  }
}
```

I've tried moving around the params, script, and query fields to different locations to see if order was important here (I'd assume not since it's a JSON object). This documentation also seems to have a similar syntax to mine: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-custom-score-query.html but still I'm having no luck.

The error I'm receiving is:

```
"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [custom_score]."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like `custom_score` is deprecated, according to:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-custom-score-query.html

Looks like `function_score_query` or `script_score` are the right tools to use:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Also, if it weren't deprecated, custom_score would need to be inside a query.